# 2273. Find Resultant Array After Removing Anagrams (Leetcode question)

Tags: c++, string, anagram

In my code at line it is showing index -97 outofbound. Why it is showing that? Where is the problem with my code?

I don't understand why it is showing. What is wrong with my code or my logic?

```
class Solution {
public:
vector<string> removeAnagrams(vector<string>& words) {

        bool ans = true;
        for(int i=1;i<words.size();i++){
            int temp[26]={0};
            for(int j=0;j<words[i].size();j++){
                int x = words[i][j];
                int y = words[i-1][j];
              int check=x-97;
              int check1 = y-97;
           
                temp[check]++;  // at this place it is showing error 
                temp[check1]--;  //  at this place it is showing error
            
            }
            for(int k=0;k<26;k++){
                if(temp[k])  ans =false;
            }
            if(ans==true){
                words.erase(words.begin()+i);
                i--;
            }
    
        }
        return words;;
    }

};
```

Comment: Find out the test case for which it fails, and the data used. Then create a [mre] with the test data hard-coded into the program. And [*debug*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) the program locally on your own system. As a ***guess*** you need to add a [`std::isalpha`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha) check.

Comment: And you should really avoid using [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) like `97`. Do you mean the ASCII code for `'a'`? Then use `'a'` instead. And note that this will not work for non-ASCII systems.

Comment: i tried that but to locate problem i wrote 97 but the same error arises

Comment: And erasing elements from the container you're iterating over is not a good idea. Use iterators instead of indexes, and check what `words.erase(...)` [*returns*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase#Return_value).

Comment: giving me same problem bro i dont know why : |

Comment: `for(int j=0;j<words[i].size();j++){ if (!std::isalpha(words[i][j]) || !std::isalpha(words[i-1][j])) { continue; } ...` Or something similar. Or just a simple range-check of `check` and `check1` before you use them as indexes.

Comment: And the lesson for today: Don't use such sites to learn basic concepts or languages. Use them when you have a very firm grasp of the language, knows algorithms and data-structures well, and have some experience writing code. Then you can use them as puzzles or brain-teasers when you have some free time over. They are ***not*** any kind of teaching, learning or tutoring resource for beginners.

Comment: Without example input that reproduces the error, this question does not meet the site's requirements for a debugging question. In addition, with such a sparse description of the problem, I don't see this question being found by anyone with a similar question in the future.

Comment: *"what is wrong with my code or my logic"* -- perhaps you could explain your logic, instead of relying on us inferring it from your code? If you made a mistake and your code does not accurately represent your intended logic, there is little hope of readers guessing your intent.